# Facing Issue with Connecting Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

it Seems like I can't connect Google Analytics Properly with my Website.

I am running a WordPress website where I would like to Integrate Analytics. I tried using both site kit and monster insights plugin as well as manually Adding the tag in the header.

Every time I visit the site, I see the gtag in the developer tools> source. But I don't get any real-time updates or report snapshots of visitors on the Analytics Dashboard it's stuck to 0.

Comment: If you're using GA4, are you adding the Data Stream ID to the plugin? And are you using GA4 or Universal Analytics?